# Django L10N can't see my locale path?

Tags: python, django, localization

I know there is a lot of topics telling the same thing, but I wasn't able to find a solution on any of them.
I created a new django project.
Here is my only template:

```
{% load i18n %}
[...]
<h1>{% trans "Please translate me" %}</h1>
<h1>{{ _("Please translate me") }}</h1>
<h1>{% blocktrans %}Please translate me{% endblocktrans %}</h1>
<p>{% trans "Password" %}</p>
<p>{{ _("Password") }}</p>
<p>{% blocktrans %}Password{% endblocktrans %}</p>
<h1>{% get_current_language as lang %}{{lang}}</h1>
<p>LOCALE_PATHS = {{ s }}</p>
[...]
```

As you can see, I am trying three different translation method: trans and blocktrans tags, and even _("string") call.
These lines are juste below a small form used to change the language. No need to copy it here, you will see that it works just fine.

Here is the view calling the template:

```
def welcome(request):
    from djp import settings
    s=settings.LOCALE_PATHS
    return render(request, 'welcome.html', locals())
```

My settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en_us' # EDIT
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

gettext = lambda x: x
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en_us', gettext('English')),
    ('fr_fr', gettext('French')),
    ('de_de', gettext('German')),

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'), 
)
```

I also have the *django.core.context_processors.i18n* and the *django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware* lines, and I added the *url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))* line in urlpatterns.

Now, after *./manage.py makemessages -l fr_fr*, I open the django.po file, remove all #,fuzzy lines and translate all strings except for 'Password', which Django automatically translates:

```
[...]
#: templates/welcome.html:30 templates/welcome.html.py:31
#: templates/welcome.html:32
msgid "Please translate me"
msgstr "S'il-te-plaît traduis moi"

#: templates/welcome.html:33 templates/welcome.html.py:34
#: templates/welcome.html:35
msgid "Password"
msgstr ""
```

Then I run *./manage.py compilemessages*, get the django.mo file, and run the server.
Now this is what I get in English:

```
Please translate me
Please translate me
Please translate me

Password
Password
Password

en-us
LOCALE_PATHS = ('/media/pawantu/Data/Projets/VirtualEnvs/loc/djp/locale',)
```

In French:

```
Please translate me
Please translate me
Please translate me

Mot de passe
Mot de passe
Mot de passe

fr-fr
LOCALE_PATHS = ('/media/pawantu/Data/Projets/VirtualEnvs/loc/djp/locale',)
```

And in German:

```
Please translate me
Please translate me
Please translate me

Passwort
Passwort
Passwort

de-de
LOCALE_PATHS = ('/media/pawantu/Data/Projets/VirtualEnvs/loc/djp/locale',)
```

So, as you can see, the word 'Password' is correctly translated (by Django I guess), so it means that the tags work (trans, blocktrans, and _("")), and the language is correctly changed.
But my translations doesn't show up. I tried to clean up the cache of my browser, it didn't fix it.
What do you think is the problem here? Is it possible that Django can't find my locale directory, even with LOCALE_PATHS tuple set up?

**Django version: 1.6.5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we can read on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/deployment/

> The LocaleMiddleware can only select languages for which there is a
>   Django-provided base translation. If you want to provide translations
>   for your application that aren't already in the set of translations in
>   Django's source tree, you'll want to provide at least a basic one as
>   described in the Locale restrictions note.

That explains why my translation weren't used.
But:

> If a base language is available but the sublanguage specified is not,
>   Django uses the base language. For example, if a user specifies de-at
>   (Austrian German) but Django only has de available, Django uses de.

... explains why the word 'Password' was still translated!
Knowing this, I changed my LANGUAGES to

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('fr', gettext('French')),
    ('de', gettext('German')),
)
```

... and adapted my locale subdirectories names to match it.
A list of what languages Django supports can be found by listing the **django/conf/locale** directory (in your site-packages directory if you use virtualenv).

Answer (score 0):

First of all LANGUAGE_CODE holds your default installation LANGUAGE:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#language-code

So it should point to one language and NOT your language list:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en_us'
```

Then (you don't paste your url's I am just going to paste a sample here) in your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    ...
    yourapppurls are here
    ...
)
```

Comment: I changed LANGUAGE_CODE as you said. But if I use the i18n_patterns, I get locked on the last language of the list (here it is de-de), it seems that I cannot change language anymore, plus I now get the language in the URL, which I don't want :/